# Update one table with near values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

```
Products
------------

ID | Sales | Rank
==================
1  | 0     | 100
2  | 0     | 105
3  | 0     | 200
4  | 0     | 900

Sales

ID | Sales | Rank
==================
1  | 2000     | 99
2  | 5000     | 106
3  | 8000     | 800
4  | 2500     | 950
```

I want to update sales.products with sales.sales based on the rank. for example

```
set products.sales=sales.sales where sales.sales is nearest to product.sales
```

In the above case below will be the results of the query.

```
Products
------------

ID | Sales | Rank
==================
1  | 2000     | 100
2  | 5000     | 105
3  | 5000     | 200
4  | 2500     | 900
```

Try to find sales of the product from sales table based on rank, If not found then find anything where Product.Rank is NEAREST value to sales.rank.

thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you mean `set products.sales=sales.sales where sales.rank is nearest to product.rank`

Comment: yes , that's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because MySQL doesn't have window functions, you have to do it the "hard way". First, build a query that calculates what the minimum difference is for each product rank:

```
select p.rank, min(abs(s.rank - p.rank)) diff
from sales s
cross join products p
group by 1
```

Then use that to find which rank is closest by finding the rank with that difference, joining again and discarding all but the highest `sales` to break ties:

```
update Products
join (select p.rank, min(abs(s.rank - p.rank)) diff
     from Sales s
     cross join Products p
     group by 1) x on Products.rank = x.rank
join Sales s1 on abs(Products.rank - s1.rank) = x.diff
left join Sales s2 on abs(Products.rank - s2.rank) = x.diff
    and s2.sales > s1.sales
    and s1.rank != s2.rank
set Products.sales = s1.sales
where s2.rank is null
```

---

Since SQLFiddle is down for the count, here's the full script:

```
create table Products (ID int, Sales int, Rank int); 
insert into Products values 
(1,0,100),
(2,0,105),
(3,0,200),
(4,0,900);

create table Sales (ID int, Sales int, Rank int); 
insert into Sales values 
(1,2000,99),
(2,5000,106),
(3,8000,800),
(4,2500,950);

update Products
join (select p.rank, min(abs(s.rank - p.rank)) diff
     from Sales s
     cross join Products p
     group by 1) x on Products.rank = x.rank
join Sales s1 on abs(Products.rank - s1.rank) = x.diff
left join Sales s2 on abs(Products.rank - s2.rank) = x.diff
    and s2.sales > s1.sales
    and s1.rank != s2.rank
set Products.sales = s1.sales
where s2.rank is null;

select * from Products;
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+------+
| ID   | Sales | Rank |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |  2000 |  100 |
|    2 |  5000 |  105 |
|    3 |  5000 |  200 |
|    4 |  2500 |  900 |
+------+-------+------+
```